# 90s-00s novel about a boy with a dimension hopping device

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

Trying to find a book that I read 10-15 years ago.

The novel is about a boy which one day gets visited by himself. His other self has a device with which someone can jump from one dimension to another.

He tries the device and notes that the device is broken and that he can just jump in one direction. (His dimension was something like 378 or so and now he is in 379.)

He jumps through a lot of dimensions with (no humans/wars/..) to find a way home. A few jumps later he finds a reality were he died or so and decides to stay there.

With the help of two friends after 10 years or so he finally gets to understand the device and repairs it. He jumps to his own dimension and confronts his other self about what happened.

Turns out his other self got turned over by another self and so on. In the mean time the other self has a wife and children in his dimension so he and his friends decide to go to dimension 1 or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [*The Walls of the Universe*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4367026-the-walls-of-the-universe) (2009) by Paul Melko

> John Rayburn thought all of his problems were the mundane ones of an Ohio farm boy in his last year in high school. Then his doppelgänger appeared, tempted him with a device that let him travel across worlds, and stole his life from him. John soon finds himself caroming through universes, unable to return home—the device is broken. John settles in a new universe to unravel its secrets and fix it.
>
> Meanwhile, his doppelgänger tries to exploit the commercial technology he’s stolen from other Earths: the Rubik’s Cube! John’s attempts to lie low in his new universe backfire when he inadvertently introduces pinball. It becomes a huge success. Both actions draw the notice of other, more dangerous travelers, who are exploiting worlds for ominous purposes. Fast-paced and exciting, this is SF adventure at its best from a rising star.

[This Amazon review](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Walls-Universe-Paul-Melko/dp/0765359650) is a lot more detailed and mentions some of what you do:

> Unfortunately, the machine only goes up the universe chain, meaning Farmboy John (hereafter referred to in this review simply as "John") can't get back home, which was Prime's plan all along, as he now slides relatively effortlessly into John's life: going to college, becoming a businessman, eventually marrying and impregnating the high school cheerleader John had always been too shy to speak to.
>
> Meanwhile, after having some near-shaves in a few of the multi-universes, John eventually settles in one and gets on with his life, going to school (where he meets his best friends and eventual partners Grace and John), starting a business by introducing the pinball machine to this world, and trying to learn as much as he can about the transport device in an attempt to fix it and return home.

---

I found this by Googling your slightly edited title `90s-00s novel about a boy with a dimension hopping device` and it was the third result and first direct link to a book.